# Selenium: Selenium: How to Read only particular row from an Excelsheet based on given keyword(say: valid/invalid)

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to build a dummy framework in selenium, which fetch/read from an excel sheet which has 3 value:
[Excelsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktmfE.png)

Now my code starts with a TestNg login method which trigger ReadExcelsheet method:

```
public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {

@Test(dataProvider = "dataForSheet",dataProviderClass = ExcelRW.class)
public void testSeccussfulLogin(String Key, String Username, String Password) {
    try{
    if(Key.equalsIgnoreCase("valid")){
        Reporter.log("=====Login test case strated=====", true);
        logn.LoginWithUsername(Username, Password);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Handled "+e);
    }

}
```

}`

Now I am reading the rows and performing login action with these values
Excel reading code:

```
public class Dp_ExcelRW {

@DataProvider(name = "dataForSheet")
public static Iterator<String[]> loginData() throws Exception {

    Iterator<String[]> arrayObject = Read("E:\\F\\Excel_Sheet\\Test.xlsx","Sheet2");

    return  arrayObject;
}

public static Iterator<String[]> Read(String SheetAddress,String Sheet) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(SheetAddress);
    Workbook wb= WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh =wb.getSheet(Sheet);
    int rowCount=sh.getLastRowNum();
    int columnCount=1;sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

    //create list
    List<String []> lst=new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for (int i= 1 ; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        //array new of size equal to no. of column
        String[] arr=new String[columnCount];

        for (int j=0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            try{

                Row row=sh.getRow(i);

                if(row == null){
                    row = sh.createRow(i);
                }
                arr[0]=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
            }
            //add to list
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Row culdn't be read since:"+ e);
            }
        }
        lst.add(arr);
    }
    return lst.iterator();
}
```

But the issue is, this code fetching even the invalid keyword row as well because there is a baseTest class which has @BeforeMethod which launches the browser and navigate to the URL.
How to Read only particular row based on given keyword. Kindly advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have made some changes in your code let me know if this helps.

```
    package com.read.files;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class StackOverFlowQuest {



@DataProvider(name = "dataForSheet")
public static Iterator<String[]> loginData() throws Exception {
    Iterator<String[]> arrayObject = Read(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\needful\\Book1.xlsx","Sheet3");


    return  arrayObject;
}

public static Iterator<String[]> Read(String SheetAddress,String Sheet) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(SheetAddress);
    Workbook wb= WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet sh =wb.getSheet(Sheet);
    int rowCount=sh.getLastRowNum();
    int columnCount=1;sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
    int arrint=0;
    //create list
    List<String []> lst=new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for (int i= 1 ; i <= rowCount; i++) {
        //array new of size equal to no. of column
        String[] arr=new String[rowCount];

        for (int j=0; j < columnCount; j=j+2) {
            try{

                Row row=sh.getRow(i);

                if(row == null){
                    row = sh.createRow(i);
                }
                String testValue = row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();

                if(testValue.equalsIgnoreCase("Valid")){
                arr[arrint]=row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
                arr[arrint++]=row.getCell(j+1).getStringCellValue();
                arr[arrint++]=row.getCell(j+2).getStringCellValue();
                arrint = 0;
                }
            }
            //add to list
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Row couldn't be read since:"+ e);
            }
        }

        if(arr[0]!=null)
        lst.add(arr);
    }
    return lst.iterator();
}
}
```

Comment: No this didn't. Its still reading 3 values and so running the testSeccussfulLogin()  for 3 times.

For invalid case its launching a browser and navigating to the URL as @BeforeMethod is running before testSeccussfulLogin() every time.